# Prove that $J \cap R(1 - e) \neq \{0\}$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, direct-sum, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring and I and J be two maximal ideals of $R$ such that $I \neq J$ and $I \cap J = Re$ where $e \in R$ is idempotent.

Prove that $J \cap R(1 - e) \neq \{0\}$.

I have no clue. I tried to work by contradiction to make use of the second isomorphism theorem. I said that since $e$ is idempotent, $R = Re \oplus R(1 - e)$. Also $J + R(1-e)$ is an ideal of $R$ containing $J$ and $\neq J$ so $R = J \oplus R(1-e)$, so $J \cong Re = I \cap J$. I don't see how this can be made useful.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of $I\cap J = Re$, $I \neq J$, and $J$ maximal, we know that $Re \subsetneq J$. Let $\phi:R \to Re\oplus R(1-e)$ be the canonical isomorphism, and set $J' = \phi(J)$.

Take an element $(a, b) \in J'$ such that $b \neq 0$ (possible because $J \not \subseteq Re$). Because of $Re \subset J$, we also have $(a, 0)\in J'$, so $(a, b) - (a, 0) = (0, b) \in J'$. But $(0,b) \in \{0\}\oplus R(1-e)$, so $\phi^{-1}(0,b)$ is both an element of $J$ and of $R(1-e)$.

Comment: You said in an edit, after $Re \subset J$ and $Re \neq J$, that this is the contradiction I'm looking for. I was thinking about this. From $Re \subset J$ and $Re \cong J$, can I conclude that $Re = J$? Why?

Comment: @madmatician I was too quick reading what you had done at first. I removed it from the edit because I read what you had done a little closer and was suddenly uncertain that it was exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: Why do yo assume that the elements of $J'$ are 2- tuples? Isn't the definition $R = I \oplus J$ if $R = I + J$ and $I \cap J =\{0\}$?

Comment: @madmatician $J'$ is an ideal in $Re \oplus R(1-e)$, and as such, its elements have a natural $2$-tuple form $(a, b)$ with $a \in Re$ and $b \in R(1-e)$.

Comment: So the notation $R = I \oplus J$ means that $R = I \times J$ (a direct product)?

Comment: @madmatician As long as there are only finitely many terms, then $\oplus$ and $\times$ mean the same thing for rings, yes.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. But I am still confused. What is the precise definition for direct sum?

Comment: @madmatician Intuitively, it is the direct product, but for an infinitely long direct sum, you allow only finitely many non-zero elements. If your definition of a ring requires any ring to contain a $1$, then infinite direct sums _do not exist_. That is one reason why the tensor product is a thing. The formal definitions I use are the [category-theoretical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) ones, where $\times$ is the product and $\oplus$ is the coproduct (assuming that ring homomorphisms are not required to send $1$ to $1$, but may send $1$ to any viable idempotent).

Answer (score 3):

Assume the intersection to be zero.

We have

$$R/J = (J+R(1-e))/J \cong R(1-e)/(J \cap R(1-e)) = R(1-e) \cong R/Re,$$

but $Re = I \cap J$ is not maximal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the most "down-to-earth" proof:

As $1-e \notin J$ and $J$ is maximal, we have some $r \in R$ with $1-r(1-e) \in J$. Multiply with $1-e$ to obtain $(1-r)(1-e) \in J$, hence $(1-r)(1-e) \in J \cap R(1-e)$.

If this element is non-zero, we are done. If it is zero, we have $1-r \in Ann(1-e)=Re$. Replace $r$ by $r+j$ for some $j \in J \setminus Re$. Then $1-(r+j) \notin Re=Ann(1-e)$, but we still have $(1-(r+j))(1-e) \in J$, so this is a non-zero element of the intersection.